# Splitting a string by delimiter without any variables?

Tags: java

Can you split a string in Java without storing what has been split into variables? (Assignment requirement :()

I have tried things which worked on other programming languages however nothing I try seems to work:

(Attempting to see if the second item in a space delimited string (x) is +)

```
if ((x.split.(" ")).(1) = "+") {
            // Do something
        }

if ((x.split.(1).(" ")) = "+") {
            // Do something
        }
```

Comment: Can you quote, word for word, the requirement? `String#split(..)` returns an value of type `String[]`.

Comment: You must NOT declare any variables or make any methods which are not in this class. You may use classes from the Java library but the outputs must be stored in existing variables.

The only variable available to use is a parameter string called x and a double called x

Comment: also x.split.(" ")).(1) = "+") is purely wrong wrong wrong! Crying out for syntactical errors. You need `if (x.split(" ")[1]).equals("+")`

Comment: @user2177940 IMHO this is an artificial constraint and an extremely poor assignment.  If you don't store the result of `split` in a variable then you will inevitably end up _repeating_ the split call to get the other elements.  This is poor practise and violates the DRY ("Don't Repeat Yourself") principle.

Comment: You can't have two local parameters/variables with the same name.

Comment: @hagubear Look again.  Your parentheses are in odd places.

Answer (score 5):

Well, what is returned is of type `String[]`. So if you **know** that there will be two items, you can reference it as an `array`..

```
if(x.split(" ")[1].equals("+"))
```

**Extra Reading**

- You should look at [String Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: It isn't _like_ an array, it _is_ an array.  The only risk is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @user2177940 I put an extra `.` in by accident. Updated.

Comment: @user2177940 there shouldn't be any dot between methods name and its arguments like in code from your question `split.(" ")`.

Answer (score 1):

String.split returns an array, so this is how it could be done. Note the use of '.equals()'. In Java the == operator checks if the pointer value is the same.

```
if (x.split.(" ")[1].equals("+")) {
    // Do something
}
```

(And of course this could throw an out of bounds exception if the split wouldn't make an array of size >= 2)